# Create a separate clean database for tests in django

Tags: django

Hi I would like to create a separate empty database for tests. I read on django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/)
that :

> The default test database names are created by prepending test_ to the value of each NAME in DATABASES. When using SQLite, the tests will use an in-memory database by default (i.e., the database will be created in memory, bypassing the filesystem entirely!). The TEST dictionary in DATABASES offers a number of settings to configure your test database. For example, if you want to use a different database name, specify NAME in the TEST dictionary for any given database in DATABASES.

So I tried:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'test_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test_db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

but tests still use the default database when running them with

```
./manage.py test
```

How can I create and specify a new, empty database for tests purposes?

Comment: No, the database is, like the specifications say, not `default`, but `test_default`, so it *already* creates a test database without specifying one.

Answer (score 3):

I think you *misread* the documentation. Django automatically uses a *separate* database.

Say your config file looks like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Then Django will *not* use the `'default'` database, if the name of the database is `'FOO'`, it will create a database with the name **`test_FOO`**. Such that testing and running the Django project should - without of course "patching" this behaviour - not interfere (at least not the databases).

If you however want to specify a *different* `NAME` (or other attributes), you can add a [**`'TEST'`** key [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#test) in the databases, like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'other_db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! But when I run my selenium tests I can see that the database is populated with data from the default database. And when I create objects for instance a new user int the test and try to log in the new account, the action fails. Do you maybe have any ideas why this might be?

Comment: @madasionka: no that is very strange. Perhaps it is worth sharing all (relevant) settings. Normally by using `sqlite3`, as said in the documentation, there is no file stored in the filesystem: the database is stored in *memory*. So all queries should make no changes to the file system at all.

Comment: I looked carefully at my settings and I don't see anything suspicious. The weird thing is that it would seem that indeed the tests are somehow using a different database (since if i create a user it doesn't get created int the default database), but the chromium window with my application is using the default database.